# insert before last 2 char in javascript

Tags: javascript

How would I insert a `%` before the last 2 characters in a word?

For example:

```
var str = "Because";
```

Output:

```
Becau%se
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about

```
var str = "Because";
var len = str.length;
var x = str.substring(0, len-2) + "%" + str.substring(len-2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's been 2 for a while. I changed it as soon as a posted and noticed I'd made the mistake.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
var str = "Because";
var result = str.slice(0, -2) +"%"+str.slice(-2);
```

Comment: awesome solution. much better than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function insert(str, value, position){

   return str.substring(0,str.length-position) + value + str.substring(str.length-position);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/6WNk8/

Comment: Should not use my solution. im going through too many uncessesary steps!

Answer (score 1):

```
str.substring(0, str.length - 2) + "%" + str.substring(str.length - 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
str.substring(0,str.length-2)+"%"+str.substring(str.length-2)
```

Comment: Yes, I know that Jim Blackler comment contains this same solution. When I was writting it, I haven't noticed he already written it. This is what is happening if problem is simple ;). Also, yes, I don't like using spaces :D.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively...

```
var str = "Because",
    chars = str.split('');

chars.splice(-2, 0, '%');
str = chars.join('');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zq3Wf/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I wrote for you to do it!

```
var MyString = "Because";

// Inserts a string into another string at a given point
function InsertString(OriginalString, InsertingString, Position) {
    return OriginalString.substring(0, Position) + InsertingString + OriginalString.substring(Position, OriginalString.length);
}

// You can call this as well if you want it n positions from right
function InsertStringFromRight(OriginalString, InsertingString, CharsFromRight) {
    return InsertString(OriginalString, InsertingString, OriginalString.length - CharsFromRight);
}

// Call the function!
var Test1 = InsertString(MyString , "#", 5);
var Test2 = InsertStringFromRight(MyString , "#", 2);

alert(Test1);
alert(Test2);
```